# Pug template won't render after redirecting to new url

Tags: javascript, express, rendering, pug

Whenever I attempt to redirect to a new url with query params and then try to render it after, it doesn't want to render. If i take the additional query params off, the page will render just fine.

These are the functions to check for user logins and their profile that displays afterwards. The function is meant to send in the user's username into the url and then be grabbed by the profile function to populate the profile pug template.

```
exports.loginCheck = async (req, res) => {
    let usernameStr = req.body.username;
    let passwordStr = req.body.password;

    var userFound =  await User.findOne()
    .where("username")
    .equals(usernameStr)
    .where("password")
    .equals(passwordStr)
    .select("username email age password answer1 answer2 answer3")
    .then((account) => {
        console.log(userFound);        
        res.redirect(`/profile/${account.username}`);
        
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.render("login", {
            errorMsg: 'Username and/or password is incorrect.'
            
        });
    });
}



exports.profile = async (req, res) => {
    var param = req.params.userP;

    var userFound =  await User.findOne()
    .where("username")
    .equals(param)
    .select("username email")
    .then((user) => {
        res.render('profile', {
            username: user.username, //I get an error saying cant read '.username', but it will find the user
            email: user.email
        })
    })
    

    

}
```

The routes:

```
   app.get('/profile/:userP', routes.profile); //this one doesnt render
   app.get('/profile', routes.profile); //this one does render
   app.post('/profile/login', urlencodedParser, routes.loginCheck); //the post route after users login
```

All of these routes are meant to render the profile pug template.

I've tried doing params, query strings, messing with the form routes that post to the profile page, redirecting and rendering on both the login function and the profile function. I was hoping to post the data to the login function via the '/profile/login' route and then redirect to the profile page with the user's information or just the username sent to the profile page so I can then fill the profile page with the user's information from my database.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `async/await` with `then` blocks here:

```js
var userFound =  await User.findOne() //< async/await return value stored in userFound
//..
//..
.then((account) => { //< Return value stored in account
//..
```

In JavaScript asynchronous tasks are handled with either callbacks or if using promises then `async/await` or `then` blocks. It is best to stick with one pattern to avoid confusion. Preferably, `async/await` with `try/catch` is more readable and leads to better error handling.

Update your code like so:

```js
exports.loginCheck = async (req, res) => {
    try{
       if(req.body.username === undefined || req.body.password === undefined){
          throw new Error('req.body is empty');
       }
       const usernameStr = req.body.username;
       const passwordStr = req.body.password;
       const userFound = await User.findOne()
       .where("username").equals(usernameStr)
       .where("password").equals(passwordStr)
       .select("username email age password answer1 answer2 answer3");
       if(!userFound){ //< Will be true if userFound == null
          res.render("login", {
             errorMsg: 'Username and/or password is incorrect.'
          });
       }else{ //< userFound has a match so redirect
          console.log(userFound);        
          return res.redirect(`/profile/${userFound.username}`);
       }
    }catch(err){
       console.log(err);
       res.render("login", {
          errorMsg: 'Internal error on server'
       });
    }
}
```

```js
exports.profile = async (req, res) => {
   try{
      if(req.params.userP === undefined ){
          throw new Error('req.params is empty');
       }
      const param = req.params.userP;
      const userFound = await User.findOne()
      .where("username").equals(param)
      .select("username email");
      if(!userFound){ //< Will be true if userFound == null
          res.render("login", {
             errorMsg: 'User not found'
          });
      }else{ //< userFound has a match so redirect
         res.render('profile', {
            username: userFound.username,
            email: userFound.email
         });
      }
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.render("login", {
         errorMsg: 'Internal error on server'
      });
   }
}
```

Lastly, this route has no purpose:

```js
app.get('/profile', routes.profile);
```

You are routing this request to the `routes.profile` function but you have only designed that funtion to work with a request parameter such as `req.params.userP`.

As an aside, there is no security in place. I could guess the `username` and just type `/profile/bob123` then `/profile/sally123` etc. in the url until I get a hit. I'm sure you are still in the design/test stage so look into authentication and authorisation to protect your routes.

Comment: I have a new error now: I get a type error on my exports.logincheck, but I have body parser so the values shouldn't be undefined. It says it can't read "username" in my 'req.body.username', but it'll still redirect with the new url and render the login page with the Internal error message.

Comment: Good that means your errors are being caught now. Can you `console.log(req.body)` as the first statement in the `exports.logincheck` function? If it's undefined then it's not being parsed. Are you sending the data via a normal form or using javascript?

Comment: When I console log it first, it does give me the data back just fine, but once it reaches the try/catch, it becomes undefined. I'm sending the data through a form.

Comment: I should add that even when I console log the body inside the try/catch, the moment I try to search for the record, it'll print out undefined or say that the username/password are wrong, but those are the correct credentials in the database.

Comment: @Priest I had to test the code in a sandbox and it works perfectly. You will see I've added error handling for `undefined` values from the `req.body` and `req.params` objects. If these throw errors then make sure you have `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true} ));` and `app.use(express.json());` above your route definitions in your main file so that forms and javascript fetch/axios/postman post request can be parsed by express.

Comment: unfortunately, my pug pages still wont render after I load data into them. I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: If `req.body` is not empty and you are getting the user from the database then it may be a pug template issue. You might want to include the pug template code or ask a pug template question.

Comment: okay, thank you for all your help